# load rdf/json from URL using DotNetRDF

Tags: json, solr, rdf, dotnetrdf

I'm new to the World of triplets :-) I'm trying to use DotNetRDF to load the SOLR searchresult into a Graph using DotNetRDF.

The URL I'm getting data from is:

https://nvv.entryscape.net/store/search?type=solr&query=rdfType:https%5C%3A%2F%2Fnvv.entryscape.net%2Fns%2FDocument+AND+context:https%5C%3A%2F%2Fnvv.entryscape.net%2Fstore%2F1

The format is supposed to be "RDF/JSON". No matter what parser or what I try - I only get "invalid URI".  Have tried to load from the URL and also tried downloadning the result to a file and load from file, same error.

I'm using VS2017 and have "nugetted" the latest version of DotNetRdf.

Please help me, what am I missing?

Regards,

Lars Siden

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the JSON being returned by that endpoint is not valid RDF/JSON. It does appear to contain some RDF/JSON fragments but they are wrapped up inside another JSON structure. The RDFJSONParser in dotNetRDF requires that your entire JSON document be a single, valid chunk of RDF/JSON.

The value at `resource.children[*].metadata` is an RDF/JSON object. So is the value at `resource.children[*].info`. The rest is wrapper using property names that are not valid IRIs (hence the parser error message).

Unfortunately there is no easy way to skip over the rest of the JSON document  and only parse the valid bits. To do that you will need to load the JSON document using Newtonsoft.JSON and then serialize each valid RDF/JSON object you are interested in as a string and load that using the RDFJSONParser's Load(IGraph, TextReader) or Parse(IRdfHandler, TextReader) method.

Comment: Thanks! I have come to the same conclusion :-( alas, when I tried that yesterday - I still couldn't load the fragments into a graph object either. I think my next step will be to cut and paste parts from the "JsonRdfJunk" and see if I can get some parts to be parsed.